# Question regarding algebraic proof for Pascal's identity.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I was looking at the proof for
$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, where $n$ and $k$ are each $\ge 1$.

According to the proof, expressing the right-hand side in terms of factorials, we get
$$\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}.$$

However, I don't understand how we got $(n-k)!$ instead of $(n-k-2)!$ for the denominator in 2nd term.
The equality used is the following:

$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

So shouldn't we have $(k-1)!(n-k-2)!$ in the denominator for the second term?

I assume I'm missing something really simple, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, $(n-1)-(k-1)=n-1-k+1=n-k$

Comment: The difference of $n$ and $k$ does not change when decreasing both by $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be $n-k-2$, and, yes, you're missing something simple.

When you subtract $k-1$ from $n-1$, don't forget to distribute the $-1$ factor properly:

$(n-1)\color{blue}-(k\color{blue}-1)=n-1\color{blue}-k\color{blue}+1=n-k$.